# What is the replacement of NULLIF in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I would like to know what is the replacement of `NULLIF` in Hive? I am using COALESCE but its not serving my requirement. My query statement is something like :

```
COALESCE(A,B,C) AS D
```

`COALESCE` will return first NOT NULL value. But my A/B/C contain blank values so COALESCE is not assigning that value to D as it is considering blank as NOT NULL. But I want the correct value to be get assign to D.

In SQL I could have use `COALESCE(NULLIF(A,'')......)` so it will check for blank as well. I tried CASE but it's not working.

Answer (score 11):

Just use `case`:

```
select (case when A is null or A = '' then . . . end)
```

This is standard SQL, so it will work in Hive and elsewhere.

For your particular problem:

```
select (case when A is not null and A <> '' then A
             when B is not null and B <> '' then B
             else C
        end)
```

You can actually shorten this to:

```
select (case when A <> '' then A
             when B <> '' then B
             else C
        end)
```

because `NULL` values fail comparisons.  I would use this version but often people learning SQL prefer the more explicit version with the `not null` comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for your very quick help...:)

Comment: Sometimes, specially for fixed-width type data; using `trim(A) <> ''` can be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Another HiveQL specific option is here:

```sql
create temporary macro nullify(s string) if(s = '', null, s);
--
select coalesce(nullify(A), nullify(B), nullify(C)) as D ...
```

Comment: I like this macro solution very much, it is very helpful if your version of Hive is less than 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

NULLIF is available in Hive as of 2.3.0.

You can see it in their list of [conditional functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions).

Answer (score 0):

Just use case syntax like following below :

```
select
     coalesce(
              case when A = '' then NULL else A end
              ,case when B = '' then NULL else B end
              ,case when C = '' then NULL else C end
             ) as D
 from myTable
```

Hope can solved your problem.
Thank you..

Comment: Why do you need the `coalesce`?