# How to use IFNULL function in hive?

Tags: hiveql

As we all know ,we can use ifnull function in mysql,but there is no ifnull function in hive ,so how can we use some other function to substitute it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the replacement of NULLIF in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044835/what-is-the-replacement-of-nullif-in-hive)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`NULLIF` is available in Hive(2.3.0) version on wards.

Search `NULLIF` in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF link.

Comment: If you find it useful.Kindly Mark it as answer. I am not saying about my solution but any solution which is useful so that others benefit from it.

Comment: nullif() is not the same as ifnull(). The first one is used to set a value to null under certain condition, while the second one (the one the op is asking for) is used to set the field to a value (other than null) if its value is null.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the COALESCE or nvl function.

Source -> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF.

Search for "Conditional Functions" and you will find all of the function definitions in that section.

Comment: According to its description and result, nvl() is the correct one: "nvl(value, default_value) Returns default value if value is null else returns value (as of HIve 0.11)."